# How to pass a variable to YII createCommand Query?

Tags: yii

I want to do something like this

```
Select * from users where id = $user_id
```

But how can I achieve this in YII?

Here is what I am trying

```
$user = Yii::app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM users where user_id = "$user_id"')->queryAll();
```

which returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bindValue

```
 $user = Yii::app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM users where user_id = :user_id')
        ->bindValue(':user_id',  $user_id)
        ->queryAll();
```